# Smallest subspace containing a set of vectors is the span of those vectors.

Tags: vectors, span

Show that $$span (v_1, ..., v_k)$$ is a subspace of $$R^n$$ and is the smallest subspace containing $$v_1, ..., v_k$$.

I know if we assume $$v_1, ..., v_k$$ is an element of V where V is a subspace of $$R^n$$ and there is a w that is an element of $$span (v_1, ..., v_k)$$ then w is an element of $$a_1v_k+...+a_kv_k$$.  Thus, w is an element of V because V is a subspace.  Thus the $$span (v_1, ..., v_k)$$ is subspace in R^n.  Now how do I show it is the smallest subspace.  What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confused with your proof that the span is a subspace of $R^n$.  You show that any member of the span is a member of the subspace but that only shows it is a subset, **not** that the span is a vector space itself.  To do that you need to show that it is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication.

To show it is the *smallest* subspace that contains the given vectors, you need to show that any subspace of $R^n$ of lower degree cannot contain all of the given vectors.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint}$: The smallest subspace (of a vector space $V$) containing a subset $S$ of $V$ is the intersection of all subspaces of $V$ which contain $S$ since the (arbitrary) intersection of subspaces is again a subspace.